# How can I push view controller with storyboard identifier using LGSideMenuController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, residemenu

I have to push a detail view controller when I tap on a tableview cell using with storyboard identifier. I have already designed the view controller. Now i have to navigate to the designed screen by tapping table view cell in the left menu. I am using LGSideMenuController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
if (indexPath.row == 0) {

    ProfileViewController *profileVC = (ProfileViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:PCProfileVC];
    [self.leftMenuVC navigateToViewController:@"profileVC"];
}}

-(void)navigateToViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController{


[(UINavigationController *)[self sideMenuController].rootViewController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[[self sideMenuController] hideLeftViewAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil];}
```

Please help me to do. Thanks

Comment: What is sideMenuController, is it of UINavigationController class???

Comment: sideMenuController is a method from LGSideMenuController

Answer (score 0):

Why are you pushing viewController in rootViewController.
If this code snippet is written in your ViewController.m, then try replacing,

```
[(UINavigationController *)[self sideMenuController].rootViewController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

with

```
[[self sideMenuController].rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

If your identifier PCProfileVC is correct, then this code should work.

Kindly see this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) for information on pushing ViewController in UINavigationController.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```
YourViewControllerClass *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
 // instanciate your viewcontroller 
    [(UINavigationController *)[self sideMenuController].rootViewController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]; //push your viewcontroller 
    [[self sideMenuController] hideRightViewAnimated:YES completionHandler:nil]; //hide the menu
```

Comment: I have not getting any error or crash, but my view not to navigate the respective screen. I am using LGSideMenuController from github